# Getting Deep copy of customized JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, deep-copy

I have an JPanel and it's a generic container, it could hold varied components and use varied Layout.

My purpose is to make a deep copy of this JPanel, so that i could resize or change the backgroud color of the copied one without impact on the components in the original JPanel.

First I tried to use Clone approach, but i found Clone just copy the top level, any components in the JPanel are shallow copied, that mean i just got references of origianl components.
and then i saw some articles said it can be done by serialization the JPanel, but I get following error when I do so:

java.io.NotSerializableException:sun.awt.windows.Win32OffScreenImage

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks,
Sathish

Update::

This is the code to get deep copy.

```
 static public Object deepCopy(Object oldObj) throws Exception {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos =
                new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // A
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); // B
        oos.writeObject(oldObj);   // C
        oos.flush();               // D
        ByteArrayInputStream bin =
                new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()); // E
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bin);                  // F
        return ois.readObject(); // G
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in ObjectCloner = " + e);
        throw (e);
    } finally {
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

I am passing JPanel that contains 2panels,jtable,2buttons.
But now i get NullPointer Exception.
Is there any other code to do this?

Comment: To solve `NotSerializableException` use `implements Serializable`

Comment: Is there any other code to do this?

Comment: You say that you got a generic panel, but I guess you know how that panel got constructed? Why not just create a new instance in the same way?

Comment: @kaj: But I want a deep copy of custom JPanel.

Comment: @Satish. Deep copy of what? As I said, create the new instance in the same way as the other instance was created. It will then be identical to the other one. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because Image is not serializable. You cannot serialize an image, but what you can do is turn the image into an array, serialize it, then recover it and turn it back into an image. Heres an example:

```
public int[] getArray(BufferedImage image)
{
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int[] rgbs = new int[width*height];
    return image.getRGB(0,0,width,height,rgbs,0,width);
}

public Image getImage(int array[], int width, int height)
{
    MemoryImageSource mis = new MemoryImageSource(width,height,array,0,width);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(mis);
}
```

these methods would go inside your class that implements Serializable

Comment: I dnt have a Image inside the JPanel, it contains 2panels, 2buttons, 1jtable thats all.